Не начинается заново цикл While в Python
Простой код игры "Угадай число"
Игра проходится нормально, но при вопросе "хотите сыграть еще раз" ( и ответе "да") - игра не начинается заново. Хотя при ответе "нет" - игра заканчивается с принтом "Спасибо за игру"
В чем может быть проблема?
вот исходный код:
import random
max_number = 2
random_number = random.randint(1, max_number)
user_number = 0
attempts = 0
start_game = True
restart = 0
while bool(start_game):

    while user_number != random_number:
        user_number = int(input("угадай число (от 1 до 100):"))
        attempts += 1
        if user_number > random_number:
            print(f"число {user_number} больше, чем загаданное")
        elif user_number < random_number:
            print(f"число {user_number} меньше, чем загаданное")
        else:
            print()
            print(f"Поздравляю, правильное число {random_number}!")
            print()
            print(f"количество попыток : {attempts}")
            print("Игра окончена")
            print()



    restart = input("хочешь сыграть еще раз? \"y\" или \"n\"")
    
    if restart == "n":
        start_game = False
    if restart == "y":
        start_game = True

print("спасибо за игру!")


А какие у вас в этот момент user_number и random_number?

random number поставил тут 1-2 ( что бы быстрее угадывать)
user number ввожу тоже соответственно  либо 1 либо 2
процесс угадывания проходит как надо
но потом когда спрашиваю "хотите повторить?", то цикл start game -  не срабатывает

т.е. когда отвечаю "n" на вопрос "хотите начать заново" - цикл завершается, и пишет "Спасибо за игру" ( все работает как надо). А вот если жму "у", то цикл start game - не запускается заново
а просто пишет бесконечно строку "хотите начать сначала?"
короче работает наполовину

@Evgeniy Brodetskiy  участник @MBo  как бы намекает, что после такого как число угадано, может ли выполнится цикл while user_number != random_number:  число ведь угадано.

Внес строку "random_number = random.randint(1, max_number)" в сам цикл игры
и все заработало
но приходиться спрашивать "хотите сыграть еще раз?", по несколько раз подряд. хоть все и работает как надо)

random_number ты устанавливаешь только 1 раз, в самом начале, после этого оно не будет меняться. user_number после угадывания равно этому случайному числу, соответственно цикл больше и не выполняется.

Добавь принты перед вторым циклом, тогда станет понятно, что при повторном выполнении второго цикла у тебя не будет выполняться условие user_number != random_number. Так как значения random_number и user_number не сброшены (user_number = random_number / 1 = 1), цикл в таком случае пропускается.
while bool(start_game):
    print(random_number)
    print(user_number)
    while user_number != random_number:

Вывод в консоли:
1
0
угадай число (от 1 до 100):1

Поздравляю, правильное число 1!

количество попыток : 1
Игра окончена

хочешь сыграть еще раз? "y" или "n"y
1
1
хочешь сыграть еще раз? "y" или "n"

Для исправления ошибки нужно снова выбрать рандомно новое число, сбросить введенное пользователем число и количество попыток при выборе "y":
    if restart == "y":
        start_game = True
        random_number = random.randint(1, max_number)
        user_number = 0
        attempts = 0

В целом, код можно улучшить так:
import random

max_number = 2
random_number = random.randint(1, max_number)
user_number = 0
attempts = 0
start_game = True
# restart = 0 # это можно убрать, так как переменная создастся внутри цикла
while start_game: # bool() можно не писать

    while user_number != random_number:
        user_number = int(input("угадай число (от 1 до 100):"))
        attempts += 1
        if user_number > random_number:
            print(f"число {user_number} больше, чем загаданное")
        elif user_number < random_number:
            print(f"число {user_number} меньше, чем загаданное")
        else:
            # print()
            # print(f"Поздравляю, правильное число {random_number}!")
            # print()
            # print(f"количество попыток : {attempts}")
            # print("Игра окончена")
            # print()

            # Это можно заменить на:

            print(f"\nПоздравляю, правильное число {random_number}!\n\n"
                  f"количество попыток : {attempts}\n"
                  f"Игра окончена\n\n")

    restart = input("хочешь сыграть еще раз? \"y\" или \"n\"")

    if restart == "n":
        start_game = False

    if restart == "y":
        start_game = True
        random_number = random.randint(1, max_number)
        user_number = 0
        attempts = 0

print("спасибо за игру!")

